# Testing Accessibility on Emulated Device (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-6.0-marshmallow, talkback

I want to test the accessibility of my app in emulator (particularly `Talkback`) but it seems that the option is missing in emulator. Here is the screen shot from the emulator in accessibility settings:

[image]

There are two options `"ClockBack"` and `"QueryBack"` which I couldn't find on my phone with the same android version. Here is the screenshot of the accessibility setting of my phone:

[image]

I searched to learn about `"ClockBack"` and `"QueryBack"` to see if they are replacement of `Talkback` in emulator but I couldn't find anything.

Does any one know what is the functionality of `"ClockBack"` and `"QueryBack"`? And more over how to enable `Talkback` in emulator?

......

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It seems that the emulator doesn't contain `Talkback` by default so after downloading `"TalkBack" apk` and install it on the emulator, the option has been enabled.

Comment: You did not mention how to download the apk.

Comment: Drag and drop the apk into the open emulator

Comment: APK can be downloaded here: https://apkpure.com/google-talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback/download?from=details

Comment: I don't know how secure it is downloading and installing from that link.
I would just search for Talkback in the emulator PlayStore and install the suite from there.

Comment: It is better to build it from the source using this repo https://github.com/google/talkback instead of downloading it from unknown source provided by @ReubenTanner due security reasons

Comment: There is no need to download a APK which can be insecure. You can choose an Android Emulator with the Google Play store directly integrated in it, from the AVD Manager (Android Studio, Tools menu). For instance install a Pixel 4 API 30. Then sign in to your Google Account inside the Play Store and install the Google Accessibility Suite. Be careful, if you are stuck in the "downloading..." just reboot the emulator.

Comment: @PiotrBadura The last release of that repository was in 2018. The build script still refers to Java 8, which came out in 2014. Is anyone sure that project is up to date?

Answer (score 42):

Update: It's easier to install the Android Accessibility Suite from the Google Play Store. It will update your Settings->Accessibility menu to include TalkBack as an option.

Comment: Yes, the AVD Manager now let you choose some emulators with the Google Play Store directly integrated with it.

Answer (score 9):

The emulators don't contain Talkback by default. You need to install an Emulator with Google Play then Download TalkBank.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [official documentation](https://github.com/google/talkback) says to download the project, build the app, and drag the APK from the build folder onto the device. Worked the first time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the `TalkBack` apk from here: https://apkpure.com/google-talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback/download?from=details and then install it on your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

but can it be turned on ? I was able to adb install from this site https://rileymacdonald.ca/2018/09/07/android-test-talkback-accessibility-android-emulators/ but Settings ->Access