# Why is the talkback text for a TextView read twice and the hint read as well even if the TextView is filled?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am working on a large project, where we use `TextView`s to show text as well as a hint.

When using talkback (accessibility), I have noticed that the hint on a `TextView` is read twice.

Also even when there is text in the `TextView`, the hint will still be read.

When I use an `EditText` instead, only the second problem persists (text entered, hint is still read). This seems to be normal (but confusing) Android-behaviour, since Google-Apps like the PlayStore do this as well.

But why is the `TextView` reading the hint twice, while an `EditText` is not?

---

PS: I am aware of the possibility to switch from `TextView` to `EditText`, but since we are using custom views as well that heavily depend on `TextView`, this is not a feasible option.

I am also aware of using `label for`, but I am more interested in the technical background why `TextView` reads the hint twice.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="test"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

[image: Accessibility is read twice]

Comment: This is printing in a toast?

Comment: @Ankita: No, in the talkback-developer options you can activate a visual representation of what the talkback-reader is saying: `Settings -> Accessibility -> Talkback -> Settings -> Developer settings -> Display speech output`. Easy to find, isnt it?

Comment: how can we start talkback on emulator?

Comment: @Ankita https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098548/testing-accessibility-on-emulated-device-marshmallow ... but my problem is not limited to the emulator

Comment: Did you find a solution for the same? I too face the same issue.

Comment: To this date (1.st December 2020) I have not found a solution.

Comment: You could try to set a `contentDescription`! Maybe that will work? I would try and change the text `TEST`  above in the ToolbarLayout, to be sure that it is not the text that you hear the first time, although I do not think that is the problem.

Comment: @hamena314 what is the name of this activity in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @ hamena31 did you get solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I reported it as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/274627677

I found a workaround that seems to work as expected:

```kotlin
view.accessibilityDelegate = object : AccessibilityDelegate() {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfo) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
        info.hintText = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's announcing twice because you're setting the 'hint' to the TextView since it reads its own text as a content description, and 'hint' is being used as text when there is no text set. I think it's not being handled correctly in the TextView.