# I need an adb command to enable an android accesibility option

Tags: adb

I'm trying to start voice access but the phone I'm using doesn't have the accessibility menu is there a direct adb command to get it started?

Answer (score 7):

To start the accessibility service you can use:

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService
```

And to stop:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.google.android.marvin.talkback
```

Comment: com.google.android.marvin.talk is the package name?

Comment: Yes. It's the package name of talkback app used to enable and disable accessibility. If you're using emulator you will need to download it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098548/testing-accessibility-on-emulated-device-marshmallow). Hope this will clear your doubt.

Comment: so if the i changed the package name to 'com.android.cts.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess' then it would be 'shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.cts.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess/com.android.cts.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess.TalkBackService' ?

Comment: Given you have TalkBackService in your package "com.android.cts.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess".

Answer (score 4):

`NEW_SERVICE` can be enabled by

```sh
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services NEW_SERVICE
```

However, this can also disable all `OTHER_ENABLED_SERVICES`. So It's better to use

```sh
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services OTHER_ENABLED_SERVICES:NEW_SERVICE
```

Here we use `:` to join services. The content of `OTHER_ENABLED_SERVICES` can be known using

```sh
adb shell settings get secure enabled_accessibility_services
```

The content of `NEW_SERVICE` can be extracted from the result too, if you turn on the service maually.

`NEW_SERVICES` can be disabled using

```sh
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services OTHER_ENABLED_SERVICES
```